# Json call invalid due to @symbol

Tags: jquery, json

I validated the Json online and seems to be valid. I called the json array key but editor throwed Parsing error: Unexpected character '@'

The editor is Visual studio code and code seems not be working due to @ symbol

```
<script>
{
    "@context": "https://example.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "@id": "https://examples.com/#organization",
            "name": "",
            "url": "https://examples.com/",
            "sameAs": []
        }
    ]
}
var x = @context;
var y = @graph[0].@type;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
</script>
```

Need to console log the values

Comment: You need to assign your object to a variable first, i.e. `var data = { ... }`, and then you can access the `@context` value by doing `data['@contenxt']`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you need to first assing your object to a variable first. From there, you can then access the object key-value pairs by using the square bracket notation.

You cannot use `@` character in dot notation. If you want to access the value defined by the key `@context`, you need to use `d['@context']` and not `d.@context`.

```js
var d = {
    "@context": "https://example.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "@id": "https://examples.com/#organization",
            "name": "",
            "url": "https://examples.com/",
            "sameAs": []
        }
    ]
}
var x = d['@context'];
var y = d['@graph'][0]['@type'];
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Good Morning Terry! Thanks for your thoughts on this matter. But I'm adding snippets to our client website, hence, I can't assign variable to their existing database. Is there a possibility to get the values  without assigning variable?

Comment: @sajz It's unclear what you mean by "can't assign variable to their existing database". That's what you're doing in your original snippet anyway?